# How do I add a title to a grouped pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, histogram

I am trying to change the title, the y axis title and the x axis numbers of histograms made from a grouped pandas dataframe. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from random import randint
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

a = []
for i in range(200):
    a.append(randint(0, 1))
b = []
for i in range(200):
    b.append(randint(1, 3))

d = {'A': a, 'B': b}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_group = df.groupby(['A'], as_index = True)

df_group.hist(bins=5)
```

This is what I see when I run the code:
[Original Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjRvO.jpg)

What I would like to do is to edit it in python to look like this (I made this in paint):
[Edited Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlYBk.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `df.groupby('A').plot.hist(bins=5, subplots=True, legend=True)`?

Comment: No. I just get this: [PREFu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PREFu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the result you want.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from random import randint
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

a = []
for i in range(200):
    a.append(randint(0, 1))
b = []
for i in range(200):
    b.append(randint(1, 3))

d = {'A': a, 'B': b}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_group = df.groupby(['A'], as_index = True)

ax = df_group.hist(bins=5)
for i in range(len(ax)):
    ax[i][0][0].set_title(f"A-{i}")
```

I just iterated through the subplots and rename them manually.

Comment: This did help me with the title. Thank you. But I still need to change the x-axis's numbers to only three numbers to match the corresponding bars. I also would like to give the y-axis a title as well. Like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlYBk.jpg)

Comment: By using set_ylabel, set_xticks and set_xticklabels, and using the method you used for the titles above, I was able to make the plot I wanted to. Thank you.